FullCalendar Month View show time range
I need to see the event time range in month view. Now I see only the start time. I read the documentation and didn't find a way to change this format.eventTimeFormat is not working because the end date is null.

The Month view is a specific type of DayGrid view called dayGridMonth. Make sure you set plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
initialView: 'dayGridMonth'

@BartMcEndree Yes. Checked. I use next plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin]. And i use next views: timeGridDay timeGridWeek dayGridMonth.

Check the value you set for displayEventEnd https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventEnd

@BartMcEndree YES! It works. Thanks!

please provide details of the value you had so I can include it in the answer and help others with the same issue.

@BartMcEndree For me it was false. I changed it to true in dayGridMonth view settings.

Check the value you set for displayEventEnd https://fullcalendar.io/docs/displayEventEnd
This setting controls whether or not to display an event’s end time.
It is a Boolean with the defaults:
false // for dayGridMonth and dayGridWeek views
true  // for timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, and dayGridDay
